# ggplot facet_wrap as_labeller does not display the new sequence

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

I created a vector of ordered names and tried to replace each panel title with the ordered one (e.g., Jessie with 1. Jessie, Marion with 2.Marion, etc.). But, I am getting NAs for each panel title instead. Any hints what is going wrong.

With the NAs
[image: picture with the NAs]

With the labeller commented out
[image: picture without with the labeller commented out]

```
list.top.35.names.ordered <- data.frame( cbind(order = c(1:35),list.top.35.names)) %>% 
  unite( name.new, c("order" ,"list.top.35.names"), sep = ".")

  list.top.35.names.ordered <- list.top.35.names.ordered$name.new[1:35]
```

> str(list.top.35.names.ordered)
>         chr [1:35] "1.Jessie" "2.Marion" "3.Jackie" "4.Alva" "5.Trinidad" "6.Ollie" ...

```
data.babyname.all %>% 
  ggplot( mapping = aes(x = year, y = perc, fill = sex)) +
  geom_density(stat = "identity", position = "stack" , show.legend = F ) +
  facet_wrap(~name, ncol= 7, nrow =5, labeller= as_labeller(list.top.35.names.ordered)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('#E1AEA1','#9ABACF'))  +
  geom_point(data = most.unisex.year.and.value, mapping = aes(x =  year, y = perc), 
             size = 3, 
             fill = "white", 
             color = "black", 
             shape = 21) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(0,.50,1), labels= c("0%", "50%","%100")) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(1940, 1960, 1980,2000), labels= c('1940', "'60","'80",'2000')) +
  geom_text(mapping = aes(x =x , y = y , label = label),  check_overlap = F, na.rm = T, position = position_dodge(width=.9),  size=3) +
  theme_minimal() + #set theme
  theme(
          text = element_text(size = 10),
          axis.title.x = element_blank(),
          axis.title.y = element_blank(),
          panel.grid = element_blank(), 
          panel.border = element_blank(),
          plot.background = element_blank(),
          axis.ticks.x = element_line(color = "black"),
          axis.ticks.length =unit(.2,'cm'),
          strip.text = element_text(size = 10, margin = margin(l=10, b = .1)))
```

Comment: Your problem is not reproducible with this code, even with `library(babynames)` installed. How do you obtain: list.top.35.names?

Comment: It really doesn't matter what list of 35 names I pick. The point is from the babynames dataset you need  to filter those 35 names. Let's say here is my list of names list.top.35.names = c("Jessie", "Marion", "Jackie", "Alva", "Ollie", "Jody", "Cleo", "Kerry", "Frankie", "Guadalupe", "Carey", "Tommie", "Angel", "Hollis", "Sammie", "Jamie", "Kris", "Robbie", "Tracy", "Merrill", "Noel", "Rene", "Johnie", "Ariel", "Jan", "Devon", "Cruz", "Michel", "Gale", "Robin", "Dorian", "Casey", "Dana", "Kim", "Shannon")

Comment: the next step is to  babyname %>% filter( name %in% names list.top.35.names) and then plot. It is okay to plot just till end of facet line. The rest of the ggplotting lines are unimportant.  You should be able to reproduce the error now.